# How to avoid "is not a function" error in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, video

I have a code to remove the milliseconds of a video duration, but when I try to remove it with `c1seconds.setMilliseconds(0)` but I get the error `is not a function`.

Here is my code:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
setInterval(function asas() {
if(video.readyState > 0) {
    var minutes = parseInt(video.currentTime / 60, 10);
    var seconds = video.currentTime % 60;
    var c1seconds = seconds.setMilliseconds(0);
test.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + c1seconds;
}
}, 0100);
```

Note: I am a beginner in javascript.

Comment: The value of `seconds` is a plain number. There is no "setMilliseconds()" method available for numbers.

Comment: Also you don't need (or want) `parseInt()` before that, you want `Math.floor()`.

Comment: Also also jQuery does not have anything to do with stuff like this.

Comment: @Pointy The value of seconds is not a plain number as the number goes from video current time

Comment: 2) I don't know how to use `Math.floor()`

Comment: No, it is in fact a number. You can `console.log(typeof seconds)` if you don't believe me. `parseInt()` returns a number, and `%` returns a number. There is nothing else that `seconds` can be.

Comment: Here you can see my function and it HAVE milliseconds https://codepen.io/alexvambato/pen/jOdVOMa

Comment: The error `TypeError: seconds.setMilliseconds is not a function` is literally telling you that there is no such function as "setMilliseconds" available for a number value. You clearly have not even tried to check what the type of `seconds` is.

Comment: And can I do something so that the function not shoes the time with milliseconds as `0:1.57075`  and show the seconds in this format `0:1`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255839/discussion-between-eliseo-and-pointy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not use `seconds.setMilliseconds(0);` and use the `Math.floor(video.duration % 60)`
Here is the solution code:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
setInterval(function asas() {
if(video.readyState > 0) {
var minutes = Math.floor(video.duration / 60);
var seconds = Math.floor(video.currentTime % 60);
test.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
}, 0100);
```